# Regular expression to reduce mnemonic to first 3 letters only

Tags: mnemonic-seed, regular-expression

Since only the first 3 characters for the English-language mnemonic matter, I prefer to reduce the words to just the first 3 letters only, for cold storage purposes. I would like to do this with a regular expression, to avoid manual errors.

What would be the shortest regular expression to do this? Note that I want a newline at the end. I will post my current solution, looking forward to see a shorter one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `(\w{3})\w*` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/cz9W57/1)) or `(?:^| )(\w{3})` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/vGk7Yk/1)), whatever you prefer. There are a lot of other solutions possible as well.

You didn't provide a language, hence my solution to generic regex outside of language implementations should be advantageous.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't specify a language. I especially like your 1st solution: `echo "${MNEMONIC}" | ruby -e "puts ARGF.read.gsub(/(\w{3})\w*/,'\1')"`. Can't get the other one to work in Ruby though. Thanks also for the [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) examples.

Answer (score 3):

What I currently have:

`echo $(echo "${MNEMONIC}" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/^\(...\).*$/\1/' | tr "\n" " ")`